# How do I archive a user from a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, users

I want to archive users from a plugin, but can't seem to find the appropriate method to do so (not even in the control panel). I can suspend, delete, but not archive.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're referring to the `archived` column in the `craft_users` table in the database.

Originally we were going to use that as a way to "soft delete" different elements in Craft (Users, Entries, etc.), but never got around to implementing it for various reasons, so there is no UI for it and no backing code to support it currently.

Comment: So, I guess it's best to use 'suspended' as a way to keep users' data in the system, without the user being able to login?

Comment: That'll definitely do it!

Comment: Did you decide against these soft deletes, @BradBell, or could one hypothetically submit a feature request in support of the effort?

Comment: @MattStein Essentially this is the FR: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/867

Comment: I guess user archiving serves a slightly different purpose than soft delete then. My ideal case would be closing (but not deleting) user accounts to preserve authorship even after they've left the site or organization.